# Rearrange/Interchange nested json array key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

How to rearrange the position in nested object .
     "nextChildLogic": "AND", key value need to be moved to after "nextChildLogic" key and value

```
Original input:

[
  {
    "bankId": 6111,
    "ruleSetId": 0,
    "name": "qewrf",
    "status": "Active",
    "defaultAuthMode": "otp",
    "description": "qweerrr",
    "rules": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Suggestion",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "CRITICAL",
            "level": "first",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "level": "second",
            "type": "group",
            "nextChildLogic": "AND",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Equals",
                "value": "1212",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              },
              {
                "logic": "AND",
                "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
                "condition": "Equals",
                "value": "1222",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              }
            ],
            "groupLogic": "OR"
          },
          {
            "logic": "OR",
            "parameter": "Merchant Name",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "11111111111",
            "level": "first",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "level": "second",
            "type": "group",
            "nextChildLogic": "AND",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Contains",
                "value": "11111112",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              },
              {
                "logic": "AND",
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Contains",
                "value": "1111111113",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              }
            ],
            "groupLogic": "OR"
          }
        ],
        "modeOfAuth": "otp"
      }
    ],
    "user": "admin"
  }
]
```

Expected output:
    I want to interchange key and value with each other using loop, and i want desired output like

```
[
  {
    "bankId": 6111,
    "ruleSetId": 0,
    "name": "qewrf",
    "status": "Active",
    "defaultAuthMode": "otp",
    "description": "qweerrr",
    "rules": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "parameter": "Risk Engine Suggestion",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "CRITICAL",
            "level": "first",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "level": "second",
            "type": "group",
            "nextChildLogic": "AND",
            "groupLogic": "OR"
            "conditions": [
              {
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Equals",
                "value": "1212",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              },
              {
                "logic": "AND",
                "parameter": "Risk Engine Score",
                "condition": "Equals",
                "value": "1222",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "logic": "OR",
            "parameter": "Merchant Name",
            "condition": "Equals",
            "value": "11111111111",
            "level": "first",
            "type": "condition"
          },
          {
            "level": "second",
            "type": "group",
            "nextChildLogic": "AND",
            "groupLogic": "OR"
            "conditions": [
              {
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Contains",
                "value": "11111112",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              },
              {
                "logic": "AND",
                "parameter": "Merchant Name",
                "condition": "Contains",
                "value": "1111111113",
                "level": "second",
                "type": "condition"
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
        "modeOfAuth": "otp"
      }
    ],
    "user": "admin"
  }
]
```

All the "groupLogic" key and value interchanged before "conditions": array.

Comment: Why does it matter? They're both keys/values in the same object.

Comment: ya..need to interchange "groupLogic": "OR"  field  to before "conditions"@Andy

Comment: I think the point is that objects should not be thought of as ordered collections.  In most important senses, `{x:1, y: 2}` should be considered equivalent to `{y: 2, x: 1}`.  So **why** do you want to interchange them? Is there a more fundamental issue here?

Comment: Can  you show the output you're looking for?

Comment: @ScottSauyet ... In backend, We are forming a logic based on 'groupLogic' value ie replacing 'OR' with || so It will automatically converts 'OR' as || followed by the 'condition'

Comment: @ScottSauyet : I have added expected result in my question

Comment: JSON is meant as a serialization format, with either end deserializing it into  an appropriate data structure.  (This happens to be very easy in JS.)  If your back-end is treating it as a string without converting it to a useful structure, then you have all sorts of problems to contend with.  But if it does become a useful structure, then the order of the properties shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Also, why "using only for loop"?  If I were to even attempt this, it would be with nested `map` statements.